# Need to check is an element present or not in selenium

Tags: selenium

I am writing a function where I need to check if an element is present or not . 
I am using Pom with page factory .

So my object would be like below in the interface file

```
@FindBy(how=how.name,using="field_20_1") public Webelement title
```

My function is

```
CheckElement (WebElement element) {
    // I am not be able to check if the element is present or not 
    //(I need to throw an exception if the element is not present) 
}
```

Comment: So is there a question for us?

Comment: Sorry that you are not able to understand , I am not able to check if an element I'd present or not

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to perform a check if `element` is null after performing the `FindBy`

Comment: I can't do that because. The elemnt when it comes to the fucntion that I am creating , is has 'by.name: field_13_1'

Comment: So how can I use driver.findby .I need to know how to extract the tag and the property from it

Comment: I'm not sure what programming language it is you're using, but to find an element by Name in C# I use `IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("NameOfElement"));` where `driver` is an `IWebDriver`. If `element` is null, then it hasn't been found